# what do you call a group of people sharing the same language?

Tags: word-request

How should I say that a group share the same language?

- chorus
- assemblage

Are there any other idioms, expressions or phrases that expresses the meaning?

Comment: See ethnicity and ethnic group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"**Ethnical groups**" may be taken to refer to sets of individuals sharing a common language as well as common traditions or cultural heritage.

You could also use [language]-speaking group *(and any other word: club/class/folk/etc.)*:

- English-speaking group
- Russian-speaking class
- Spanish-speaking folk

Answer (score 2):

You would describe the group as being colingual, though "colingual" is not a commonly used word and  is mainly used in academic settings. In everday English you would just say "[the group] share a common language"

Answer (score 2):

The simplest is: [language] + speakers.

For example:

- English speakers
- Spanish speakers

Answer (score 0):

They are **native speakers of {language}**

That phrase can be used in almost any context. It refers to those who have heard {language} being spoken since infancy and who have learned it as their first language.

Comment: They may not be native speakers.